# Regex error c#?

Tags: c#, regex

How i can use "/show_name=(.*?)&show_name_exact=true\">(.*?)

```
    Match m = Regex.Match(input, "/show_name=(.*?)&amp;show_name_exact=true\">(.*?)</i", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   // Check Match instance
    if (m.Success)
    {
        // Get Group value
        string key = m.Groups[1].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(key);
        // alternate-1
    }
```

Error, Unterminated string literal(CS1039)]
Error, Newline in constant(CS1010)]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're mixing up .NET's regex syntax with PHP's.  PHP requires you to use a regex delimiter in addition to the quotes that are required by the C# string literal.  For instance, if you want to match "foo" case-insensitively in PHP you would use something like this:

```
'/foo/i'
```

...but C# doesn't require the extra regex delimiters, which means it doesn't support the /i style for adding match modifiers (that would have been redundant anyway, since you're also using the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag).  I think this is what you're looking for:

```
@"show_name=(.*?)&amp;show_name_exact=true"">(.*?)<"
```

Note also how I escaped the internal quotation mark using another quotation mark instead of a backslash.  You have to do it that way whether you use the old-fashioned string literal syntax or C#'s verbatim strings with the leading '@' (which is highly recommended for writing regexes).  That's why you were getting the unterminated string error.